# Possible to call a javascript and action function from click

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, action, onclick

I want to call a `Javascript` function as well as issue a backend call at the moment a button is clicked.

This is my code right now :

```
<apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!objectCollection}" style="margin-left:10px" reRender="source_search">
 <apex:param name="source" value="true"/>
 <apex:param name="target" value="false"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You can use the `onclick` attribute like below.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!objectCollection}" 
  onclick="callJSFunc()" 
  style="margin-left:10px" reRender="source_search">
  <apex:param name="source" value="true"/>
  <apex:param name="target" value="false"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments below, you want to call both JavaScript and Controller's function only if the input is valid. You can achieve this with following code:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!objectCollection}" 
  onclick="if(!isInputValid()){return false}else{callJSFunc()}" 
  style="margin-left:10px" reRender="source_search">
  <apex:param name="source" value="true"/>
  <apex:param name="target" value="false"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

The idea is that the `isInputValid()` is also a JS function that will validate the input and return `true` if everything is valid, and `false` if the input is invalid. If the `isInputValid()` returns `false`, neither the controller's function, nor your JavaScript function in the `else` statement will get called.

Comment: Thanks! Another question. In this case, regardless of good/bad input when the button is clicked both the `Action` and `onclick` will execute, correct? Is there any way call the backend function in my controller via the javascript function? Because what I want to do is verify good input before I send it to the backend function

Comment: @user2582622 please, see my update.